# I'm struggling to understand user-defined functions, and how to call them in a query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create a UDF as part of my assignment. It's completely open as to what we create, and I have chose to create a function that calculates a staff member's total pay due when given the STAFF_ID and WEEK_NUM.

The code for the fuction is as follows (forgive the formatting, I'm not sure of the proper way to format it):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALCULATE_WAGES(FSTAFFID IN NUMBER, FWEEKNUM IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
WAGES NUMBER(6,3);
STAFF_ID NUMBER;
HOURS_WORKED NUMBER;
MAX_HOURS NUMBER;
HOURLY_RATE NUMBER;
OVERTIME_RATE NUMBER;
WEEK_NUM NUMBER;

CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT STAFF_ID, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM FROM STAFF_HOURS WHERE STAFF_ID = FSTAFFID AND WEEK_NUM = FWEEKNUM;

BEGIN

OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO STAFF_ID, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM;

IF HOURS_WORKED > MAX_HOURS
THEN WAGES := (HOURLY_RATE * MAX_HOURS) + (HOURS_WORKED - MAX_HOURS) * OVERTIME_RATE;
ELSE WAGES := HOURLY_RATE * MAX_HOURS;
END IF;

CLOSE C1;

RETURN WAGES;

END;
```

This function works fine when I run it on it's own in sqldeveloper as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY7ew.png). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUNID.png) are the data types for that table. A box will pop up asking me to input the arguments, and then it spits out the return value, which is also correct.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XChd2.png) for the STAFF_HOURS table.

So now I have my table full of test data, and a function that takes two arguments, and spits out the correct value.

The issue I am having now is getting that value in to a table using a select query. What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT STAFF_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, HOURS_WORKED, MAX_HOURS, HOURLY_RATE, OVERTIME_RATE, WEEK_NUM, CALCULATE_WAGES(STAFF_ID, WEEK_NUM) AS "TOTAL DUE" FROM STAFF_HOURS;
```

What I hoped this would do is select all of the rows from the table, and then on the end, tack on a new row that is equal to the value that the function returns. This would then show how much money each staff member is due for that specific week.

However, I get this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at "O015596H.CALCULATE_WAGES", line 21
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

I'm not literate enough in SQL to really know how to Google my issue, so I figured my best bet was to explain my issue here and hope someone understands.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens if you don't restrict the precision for the variable `WAGES`  by using `WAGES NUMBER;` instead of `WAGES NUMBER(6,3);` ?

Comment: Wow holy shit, that fixed it. Thanks. I cannot wait to finish this module next week so that I never have to touch SQL again lol.

Comment: If the assignment is just to create a UDF and call it from SQL, it doesn’t need to query any tables. Why not just write a mathematical function like factorial or convert to binary or something? Also, is it a course requirement to code in uppercase? That used to be popular in the 1970s but all computer languages have abandoned it for the improved readability of lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know what this means?

```
WAGES NUMBER(6, 3);
```

This has three digits (6 - 3) to the left of the decimal and three to right, so a maximum value of `999.999`.  I am guessing that this the cause of your problem.  (You can learn about data types in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832).)

You can just leave out the scale and precision and the Oracle code should work.